# The meaning of "around" in the uniqueness and existence theorem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

while learning on the uniqueness and existence theorem, I started to solve some examples and I noticed that the following is always repeated:
 
 "$f(x,y)$ and  $\frac{df}{dy}$" are continuous around $(x_0,y_0)$

I do not understand what is the mathematical expression of "around" and why is it allowed to be written?

for example $y'=\frac{1}{y-1}$ with initial condition $y(0)=2$ so $f(x,y)$ is not continuous in the point $(x,1)$ but is it possible to say that it is continuous "around" other point, $(0,2)$ for example but how do I know that $(0,1)$ is not "around" $(0,2)$

*the idea here is not solve the equation but understanding the meaning of *"around"*

Comment: "around $(x_0,y_0)$" presumably means in a [neighbourhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) of $(x_0,y_0)$ or in open set or open ball containing $(x_0,y_0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually means "topological neighborhood". It means there is an open set $U$ in the topology that contains the point $x$, and you are considering a set $N\supset U$ that is generally open, called a neighborhood.

The idea is that you want the properties of an open ball, but you don't want to confine all of your definitions to open balls. Another way to think about it, is that the author is claiming there is a reasonably large open set (it contains a ball with radius $\varepsilon>0$) around $x$ for which the statement is true, but they are not going to solve for the set for you.  Why is this happening? Exactly specifying the domain on which a theorem is true is often tedious or impossible or depends on the context, while restricting all theorems specifically to open balls would be misleadingly specific. Neighborhoods are in between.